# Fixed Push Notification Icon showing White in flutter local notification icon

Tags: flutter

My app does not know show notification icon. It only shows white circle icon. how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

**You should explore issues section that related plugin first**

[App Icon in notification is empty : shown as grey square](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/1017)